# How to upload my postgresql db in phppgadmin into postgres server on some host

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I am very beginner to PostgreSQL. I have created database with tables in phppgadmin and now I need to upload it to the remove Postgres server. I knnow username and password. What do I need for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Today I uploaded a .tar file to phpPgAdmin following this command:

```
` user:-$ pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" 
  --dbname "your-database-name" --role "postgres" --no-password --verbose
  "/home/your-username/Desktop/your-file.tar"`
```

Update the last path to the current location of your backup file.

By using this command, I upload my files in remote Postgres servers.